# How can i remove header error message from wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website theme (Theme: RT Health) didn't updated recently and I got an error in heading. The problem gone whenever I change the theme so I assume its a theme error. How to fix this?

**Error:**

> class="home page-template page-template-elementor_header_footer page page-id-46 wp-custom-logo wp-embed-responsive global-layout-no_sidebar elementor-default elementor-template-full-width elementor-kit-687 elementor-page elementor-page-46">

[image]

Try editing theme file but not work

Comment: Do you have a child theme? That error could be related to header.php around `body_class()`

Comment: Please share your header.php file code.